# How to add a html datalist field to a meteor aldeed:autoform?

Tags: select, meteor, drop-down-menu, meteor-autoform, html-datalist

I populated a select input field with a collection in aldeed:autoform.

Field Declaration

```
{{> afFormGroup name="patientID" type="select" options=patientIDs}}
```

Helper

```
patientIDs:function () {

    return Meteor.users.find({}).map(function (user) {
        return {label: user.profile.firstName, value: user._id};
    });

}
```

But it turned out to be the drop down too large to select an option. Therefore I need to implement a functionality similar to [HTML datalist](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist) in the autoform. How to implement this in meteor aldeed:autoform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a select2 add-on for autoform, which might help get you what you want. See [here](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform-select2).